# What if running a function longs more than block time?

Tags: solidity, transactions, block-interval, view, pure

In a blockchain with a typically small block time such as Polygon (or any other chain in general), what happens if executing of a
a) transaction
b) view function
longs more time than a block time?

Suppose that we are reading some info from blockchain in a view function, is data returned by the function valid in such circumstance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, because EVM based blockchains are not Turing complete. Any transaction is eventually terminated [by exhausting all of its gas](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/).

Transaction maxes out the gas usage as the max gas allocation per block, so a transaction can never exceed available gas allocated for one full block

Comment: what about `view` functions? what happens to them if they took longer than block time?

Comment: `view` functions are similarly limited by the gas on `eth_call` even though gas is never spent. This protects against accidentally (or purposefully) doing a denial-of-service attack against the RPC node.